# Apache flink-kafka Adding multiple consumers in single flink-kafka consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

```
I am reading a "ABC" topic which have 5 partitions
```

but actually when i created a consumer group (i.e. Flinkkafkaconsumer09)it has only one consumer instance and that consumer is consuming all partitions.

```
I am trying to have a consumer group with 5
```

consumer instances in it cause,I need 1 consumer for 1 partition.

```
Any suggestions to help me out! 


This is what I am getting
```

GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
    console-consumer-81434         CT9                            0          1               1               0               **consumer-1***/127.0.0.1
    console-consumer-81434         CT9                            1          7               7               0               **consumer-1***/127.0.0.1
    console-consumer-81434         CT9                            2          1               1               0               **consumer-1***/127.0.0.1
    console-consumer-81434         CT9                            3          3               3               0               **consumer-1***/127.0.0.1
    console-consumer-81434         CT9                            4          5               5               0               **consumer-1**_/127.0.0.1

```
Expected Result -->(See the Owner COlumn)

GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
console-consumer-81434         CT9                            0          1               1               0               **consumer-1_**/127.0.0.1
console-consumer-81434         CT9                            1          7               7               0               **consumer-2_**/127.0.0.1
console-consumer-81434         CT9                            2          1               1               0               **consumer-3**_/127.0.0.1
console-consumer-81434         CT9                            3          3               3               0               **consumer-4**_/127.0.0.1
console-consumer-81434         CT9                            4          5               5               0               **consumer-5**_/127.0.0.1
```